# ¿Cómo puedo recuperar el Locale que me pide el usuario en C#?

Tags: c#

Primero que todo, pido disculpas no sabia como formular la pregunta.
Lo que ocurre es que yo tengo en proyecto o solución, un Resources.en-US.resx y un Resources.resx.

es obvio que el que se llama solo Resources es el por defecto.
Ahora mismo tengo esos 2, pero puedo tener mas idiomas en mi app, que por cierto es una console app.

el caso es que no se como hacer, para que si el usuario me escribe en la consola US o el idioma que sea, (por ejemplo FR si lo tuviese), poder cambiar de resources.

el problema reside en que el usuario te va a poner US o FR, no te va a poner en-US.

Entonces, que puedo hacer?
muchas gracias

Comment: analiza este articulo https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/communitydocs/net-dev/csharp/international-apps  ya que no gusto como respuesta al menos que quede como comentario

Answer (score 5):

Lo que yo haría sería obtener un listado de todos los posibles `locale` (usando `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)`) y luego hacer un `Contains` de lo que introduzca el usuario por teclado. Si solo hay una opción, seleccionaría esa. En caso contrario, mostraría por pantalla las posibles opciones para que el usuario seleccionara la correcta.

Te muestro un código de ejemplo. Es posible que debas ajustar algo y deberás gestionar posibles entradas erróneas del usuario, pero creo que te harás una idea.

```
Console.WriteLine("Introduzca cultura");
var cultura = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

var listaCulturas = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).Select(x => x.Name.ToUpper());
var culturasCoincidentes= listaCulturas.Where(x=>x.Contains(cultura));

if (culturasCoincidentes.Count() == 1)
{

    Console.WriteLine($"Cultura seleccionada: {culturasCoincidentes.First()}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Elija la cultura de la lista seleccionando su numero");
    int indice = 1;
    foreach(var cul in culturasCoincidentes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{indice} - {cul}");
        indice++;
    }
    var indiceSeleccionado=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine($"Cultura seleccionada: {culturasCoincidentes.ElementAt(indiceSeleccionado-1)}");
}
```